# Can I do stateless with SOAP like REST?

Tags: rest, soap

What would prevent SOAP from being stateless for scalibility like ... REST since REST is a pattern it shouldn't depend on using XML or JSON or http ?

Comment: Keeping services stateless is one of the principals of SOA. Also, I have a hard time imagining what kind of thing would force you to use state.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : to maintain session, dont we require to use state

Comment: What does maintaining session have to do with calling services?

Answer (score 1):

For basic usage, there is no reason SOAP cannot also be stateless.  I believe some of the WS-* extensions require state to function. Some security stuff and certainly transactions cannot be done without maintaining state.